# Conversion of Accented characters( e.g characters Ç, ü, é ,â) to respective non-accented characters in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

Can anyone please help me in converting special accented characters to   their respective non-accented characters in action script (as3)? Please let me know if there is any predefined method like `toLowerCase` to do the same. If no such method exists let me know the logic for conversion. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very quick and dirty solution, but it should work. There is also some grunt work involved in building the map of characters, you may want to find a way to pull in a JSON or XML file for this purpose instead of hard-coding it in.

```
var map:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
map["â"] = "a";
map["ã"] = "a";
map["ë"] = "e";
//... complete the map using this site: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29584_01/webhelp/mdex_basicDev/src/rbdv_chars_mapping.html

function removeDiacritics($s:String):String
{
    for(var $key:String in map)
    {
        $s = $s.split($key).join(map[$key]);
    }

    return $s;
}

var s:String = "this is ã tëst";

trace(s); // "this is ã tëst";
trace(removeDiacritics(s)); // this is a test
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Marcela but I don't think mapping would be a good idea as this won't work for accented characters of other languages ( spanish,arabic etc).